# UDP based client server model

Tags: c#, udp

I am new learner of c# and i want to send a text file in the form of segments from client to server using Udp
in C#. but i do not know how to make segment of a text file and send it to the server
kindly suggest me some good solution to this problem

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow!

Give this a shot.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92846ccb-fad3-469a-baf7-bb153ce2d82b/simple-udp-example-code

Replace

```
string text_to_send = Console.ReadLine();
```

With some file IO bits from here.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks sir but I don't know how to make small packets of my text file.because my intention is to send small chunks rather then complete file.please guide me in this respect as well